# Docker keycloak getting well-known timeout

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

In my nodeJS backend, I'm using passport-keycloak-bearer to authenticate my users. However, when it's trying to fetch the well-known configuration, it time outs. If I access the URL on the browser, it works, so this is likely an issue with the docker config.

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  project-client:
    image: 'project-client:local'
    ports:
      - '5000:80'
  project-server:
    image: 'project-server:local'
    ports:
      - '3005:3005'
  keycloak:
    image: 'keycloak:local'
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: random
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: random
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /tmp/realm.json
    ports:
      - '5002:8080'
    volumes:
      - '/data/keycloak:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data'
```

The error when this is trying to authenticate is:

```
Error: Unable to get OIDC metadata from http://MY_IP:5002/auth/realms/MY_REALM/.well-known/openid-configuration: connect ETIMEDOUT MY_IP:5002
    at OIDCMatadata.getJwksUri (/app/node_modules/passport-keycloak-bearer/src/oidcMatadata.js:37:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async OIDCMatadata.getPemKeys (/app/node_modules/passport-keycloak-bearer/src/oidcMatadata.js:47:21)
    at async OIDCMatadata.pemKeyFromToken (/app/node_modules/passport-keycloak-bearer/src/oidcMatadata.js:65:18)
```

As I said, if I try to access the URL `http://MY_IP:5002/auth/realms/MY_REALM/.well-known/openid-configuration` it immediately returns the information.

I can login via the frontend as well. It immediately redirects me to the keycloak login page, and after logging in, it redirects back to my app and displays it properly. But when trying to use an endpoint which requires authentication, it times out.

This doesn't seem to be an issue with how passport is set up or the backend itself, because when developing locally (using an external keycloak server) it works perfectly.

Im able to login to keycloak normally in the browser, and can even change any of the realm settings.